# Stalling redirect until function returns (Angular/HTML)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a button that both fires a function and redirects. Is it possible to stall the redirect until the function returns?

The reason I want to do this is because I have a second function on the destination page that uses variables set by the first function as parameters, right now the redirect happens before the first function has time to set the variables used as parameters in the second function.

My button

```
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" ng-click="selectCharacter(character)" ui-sref="apply" ng-show="application">
        Select
</button>
```

html-tag calling second function with ng-init, using parameters set by the first function

```
<form ng-Submit="getCharacterInfo(apply)" ng-init="getCharInfo(current_user, current_user_realm)">
```

Comment: Why call 2 separate functions?  At least you could have the button click do both and then redirect from there.  I never use ng-submit

Comment: either you use one function, or use promises... or a combination of both. You should show some code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try removing the ui-sref attribute from the button, so it doesn't "redirect" automatically. When the `selectCharacter` function is done executing what it executes now, it can programmatically change states:

First, remove ui-sref:

```
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" ng-click="selectCharacter(character)" ng-show="application">Select</button>
```

Then, update controller to programmatically redirect:

```
$scope.selectCharacter = function(char) {
    // do whatever needs to be done here

    // redirect to the 'apply' state programmatically. Don't forget to inject the $state service
    $state.go('apply');
};
```